# Using groupby and querying that group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that I would like to group by one column (dadate) and then query another column (Place) to count only those with the value 1.

```
Leaguedata.groupby(['dadate']).query('Place == "1"').Place.count()`
```

The above is what I have tired with the error "'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'query'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the Boolean Series then sum that within group to see how many Places == 1 for each group.

```
Leaguedata['Place'].eq('1').groupby(Leaguedata['dadate']).sum()
```

Comment: Perfect - Now I feel dumb not filtering the data before grouping. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You can also do that, but if a group gets totally filtered it won't appear in the groupby output. Since the above just works with the Boolean Series for the entire DataFrame you would still get 0s for those groups